# WordPress Posts Archive Link in Menu Not Addable

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Usually u have this "all posts" checkbox, to set a link to the posts archive, on the admin page where you can edit menus, this entry isnt appearing in a theme im currently working on.

I've no idea why and how to go about this. I dont wanna add an extra patetemplate, so how can i link the archive.php in the menu?

appreciate any ideas

Comment: Did you check the Screen Options?

Comment: Screen Options- do you mean the settings i can slide out on top? If, so yes i did, enabled anythin, still no luck..

Comment: ps. i also tried it with the twenty21 theme and setting back the permalinks to default, theres still no option to ad the archive

Comment: is this archive for default posts or custom post type?

Comment: for the default posts

Comment: Create a page for it, go to settings > reading and set Post page to that page. The page will be visible than in pages.

Comment: drives me nutz, if i set a page as posts page i get the contents of the index.php not archive.php